# Identify this peg game?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image: Wooden board with peg holes]

I'm looking for help with identifying this game. The pegs are lost but can be replaced. I can't find the directions or anything on the internet in shopping or otherwise.

The board sort of looks like tic-tac-toe with lines between connected holes, but it also has the seven peg holes on each side. There is also a reservoir cup for loose pegs or maybe dice.

Comment: If the numbered holes on the side were not there, it would be a board for tapatan, aka 3 men's morris.

Comment: It can be a tic-tac-toe variant in which you can (re)move pieces. With 7 pieces on the board you always have a winner. You can place 6 without 3 in a row.

Comment: how many pegs does it come with for each side?  perhaps the 1-7 track is just for keeping score rather than part of the game?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it to be a tic-tac-toe variant in which you can (re)move pieces. Players play normally with seven pegs, but three in a row or some other pattern allow you to capture an opponent's piece which goes into the hole.  Player with most pegs on board wins.

Couldn't find anything exactly like this at BGG.
https://www.boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/16886/games-played-3x3-grid

Comment: Or a varient of https://shop.crackerbarrel.com/toys-games/games/travel-games/peg-game/606154 ?

Comment: @joedragons - No, that is a single player puzzle. You start with one hole, then use one peg to jump another peg. The jumped peg is removed. The idea is to end up with only one peg left on board. (Easy to solve if you start with reverse problem. Start with one peg, then jump an empty hole to add a peg back to the board.)